# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /home3/mafiasec/public_html/logincheck.php on line 311

Tags: php, syntax

Here's my code, it's irritating as I can't find the problem.. I have been looking into this for the past two days and can't work it out myself, I am relatively new to coding so please explain clearly what is going on because I clearly won't understand what you are saying. please give me a hand here - here's the code.

```
    <?php
session_start();
include_once("includes/db_connect.php");
if (isset($_SESSION['real_name'])){
include "mainmenu.php";
die("-");
exit();
}



error_reporting(0);


//This of course tells the website that what follows
$realip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];





if ($_POST['Submit'] && mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])){



function change($msg){
$post = $msg;
$post = str_replace(" ", "", $post); 
return $post;
}

$username = $_POST['username']; 
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($password));
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];



$date = gmdate('Y-m-d h:i:s');



$tquery = "SELECT nextlogin FROM users WHERE username='$username'"; 
$tresult = mysql_query($tquery) or die(mysql_error());
$trow = mysql_fetch_array($tresult);


if((time() < $trow['nextlogin']) ) {

$waittime=$trow['nextlogin'] - time();
die("This user has allready tried to login in the past 30 seconds! please wait $waittime seconds before you can login!");

}



$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM loginip") or die("Hack protection error Please contact admin@mafiasecrets.com and tell him about this!");
// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

$id = $row['id'];
$timeleft = $row['time'] - time();


if ($timeleft <0){mysql_query("DELETE FROM loginip WHERE id='$id'");}

}// while loop



$select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM loginip WHERE ip='$realip'");
$num = mysql_num_rows($select);

if($num>"0"){
die("Your ip has allready tried to login in the past 30 seconds, Please wait $timeleft seconds before you can login again!");
}



///check INFO
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' LIMIT 1"); 
$login_check = mysql_num_rows($sql); 
$inf = mysql_fetch_object($sql); 

if ($login_check > "0"){


        session_register('username'); 
        $_SESSION['real_name'] = $username; 



//This of course tells the website that what follows
$realip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 

   $time2 = time();    

         $timestamp = time()+60; 


$sql = "UPDATE users SET nextlogin='".strtotime ("+30 seconds")."' WHERE username='".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."'";
 mysql_query($sql);


$sql = "INSERT INTO loginip SET id = '', ip = '$realip', time = '".strtotime ("+20 seconds")."'";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
mysql_query("UPDATE lastloginname SET username='$username' WHERE ip='$realip'");

mysql_query("UPDATE users SET online='Online', onlinetime2='$time2' WHERE username='$username'");
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET apperoffline='1' WHERE username='$username'")or die("Error aper oflin");


$time1=time()+500;

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `loggedin` (`id`, `ip`, `username`, `time`) VALUES ('', '$realip', '$username', '$time1')");



$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM facebookshare WHERE username='$username'"); 
$fb_check = mysql_num_rows($sql); 


if ($fb_check == "0"){

$timef = gmdate('Y-m-d h:i:s');


?>



<?php

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `facebookshare` (`id`, `username`, `time`) VALUES ('', '$username', '$timef')");

}//not shared



?><?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ // Start looping table row  

$rank = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($rows['rank']));
$health = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($rows['health']));
$country = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($rows['country']));
$rankpoints = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($rows['rankpoints']));
$rankbar = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($rows['rankbar']));
$firstlogin = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($rows['firstlogin']));

}
?>
<?
if($_POST['a']){
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET `firstlogin`=`firstlogin`+'1' WHERE username='$username'");
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;URL=veri.php'>";
}
?>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.textbox {background-color: 222222; border-bottom: 1px solid #626262; border-left: 1px solid #040404; border-right: 1px solid #626262; border-top: 1px solid #040404; color: white; font-family: verdana; font-size: 18px;}
-->
</style>
<body bgcolor="#222222"> 


<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="4; URL=play.php"> 
<table cellpadding="0" width="100%" height="100%"> 
<td width="100%" height = "100%"><center> 
<font color="white" face="verdana" size="3">Welcome: </font><b><font color=khaki size=3 face=verdana><? echo $username ?></font></b><br>
<table width=300 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 align=center>
  <tr>
    <td height=5></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height=1 bgcolor=#444444></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height=5></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<?php

$rank_1 = "Hobo";
$rank_2 = "Citizen";
$rank_3 = "Vandal";
$rank_4 = "Thug";
$rank_5 = "Respected Thug";
$rank_6 = "Mobster";
$rank_7 = "Respected Mobster";
$rank_8 = "Assassin";
$rank_9 = "Respected Assassin";
$rank_10 = "Mafioso";
$rank_11 = "Respected Mafioso";
$rank_12 = "Underboss";
$rank_13 = "Respected Underboss";
$rank_14 = "Boss";
$rank_15 = "Respected Boss";
$rank_16 = "Godfather";
$rank_17 = "Respected Godfather";
$rank_18 = "Gangster";
$rank_19 = "Immaculate Gangster";



$rank_2_exp = "50";
$rank_3_exp = "120";
$rank_4_exp = "350";
$rank_5_exp = "1100";
$rank_6_exp = "3200";
$rank_7_exp = "6100";
$rank_8_exp = "11300";
$rank_9_exp = "15000";
$rank_10_exp = "21000";
$rank_11_exp = "30000";
$rank_12_exp = "41000";
$rank_13_exp = "52000";
$rank_14_exp = "66500";
$rank_15_exp = "82500";
$rank_16_exp = "98000";
$rank_17_exp = "128000";
$rank_18_exp = "147000";
$rank_19_exp = "170000";    
?>
<?php
$newmail = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE t='$username' AND r='0'");
$notoriouslegendskk = mysql_num_rows($newmail);?>
 <? 


if ($rankbar>=1){ 


if ($rankpoints > "$rank_19_exp"){ 
$nextrank = 0;
}else{


if ($rankpoints < "$rank_2_exp"){ $amount="$rank_2_exp"; $check="0";}
elseif ($rankpoints < "$rank_3_exp"){ $amount="$rank_3_exp"; $check="$rank_2_exp";}
elseif ($rankpoints < "$rank_4_exp"){ $amount="$rank_4_exp"; $check="$rank_3_exp";}
elseif ($rankpoints < "$rank_5_exp"){ $amount="$rank_5_exp"; $check="$rank_4_exp";}
elseif ($rankpoints < "$rank_6_exp"){ $amount="$rank_6_exp"; $check="$rank_5_exp";}
elseif ($rankpoints < "$rank_7_exp"){ $amount="$rank_7_exp"; $check="$rank_6_exp";}
elseif ($rankpoints < "$rank_8_exp"){ $amount="$rank_8_exp";  $check="$rank_7_exp";}
elseif ($rankpoints < "$rank_9_exp"){ $amount="$rank_9_exp"; $check="$rank_8_exp";}
elseif ($rankpoints < "$rank_10_exp"){ $amount="$rank_10_exp"; $check="$rank_9_exp";}
elseif ($rankpoints < "$rank_11_exp"){ $amount="$rank_11_exp"; $check="$rank_10_exp";}
elseif ($rankpoints < "$rank_12_exp"){ $amount="$rank_12_exp"; $check="$rank_11_exp";}
elseif ($rankpoints < "$rank_13_exp"){ $amount="$rank_13_exp"; $check="$rank_12_exp";}
elseif ($rankpoints < "$rank_14_exp"){ $amount="$rank_14_exp"; $check="$rank_13_exp";}
elseif ($rankpoints < "$rank_15_exp"){ $amount="$rank_15_exp"; $check="$rank_14_exp";}
elseif ($rankpoints < "$rank_16_exp"){ $amount="$rank_16_exp"; $check="$rank_15_exp";}
elseif ($rankpoints < "$rank_17_exp"){ $amount="$rank_17_exp"; $check="$rank_16_exp";}
elseif ($rankpoints < "$rank_18_exp"){ $amount="$rank_18_exp"; $check="$rank_17_exp";}
elseif ($rankpoints < "$rank_19_exp"){ $amount="$rank_19_exp"; $check="$rank_18_exp";}

/// total rankpoints - rankpoints required for current rank / rank points needed for next rank * 100

$end = $amount - $check; 


$percent = $rankpoints - $check; 


$percent = $percent / $end;
$add = $percent * 100;

if($rankbar==2){
$nextrank = sprintf ("%0.1f",$add);
}else{
$nextrank = round($add);
}

}//not undercover gangster
 ?>
<font color=white face=verdana size=2>You have <b style=color:khaki;><?php echo $notoriouslegendskk ?></b> new messages!</font><br>
<table width=300 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 align=center>
  <tr>
    <td height=5></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height=1 bgcolor=#444444></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height=5></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<font color=silver face=verdana size=1>Rank: </font><font color=white face=verdana size=1><?php echo $rank ?></font><font color=silver face=verdana size=1> | </font> <font color=silver face=verdana size=1>Rank Up: </font><font color=white face=verdana size=1><?php echo $nextrank ?>%</font><font color=silver face=verdana size=1> | </font> <font color=silver face=verdana size=1>Health: </font><font color=white face=verdana size=1><?php echo $health ?>%</font><font color=silver face=verdana size=1> | </font> <font color=silver face=verdana size=1>Location: </font><font color=white face=verdana size=1><?php echo $country ?></font><br>
</center> 
</td> 
</table> 
</body>
<?php } ?>
<?php   
} else { 

$sql = "UPDATE users SET nextlogin='".strtotime ("+20 seconds")."' WHERE username='".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."'";
 mysql_query($sql);

$failtime = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime('+5 hours'));

mysql_query("INSERT INTO loginfails SET id = '', ip = '$realip', time = '$failtime', username = '$username', password = '$password'");
$sql = "INSERT INTO loginip SET id = '', ip = '$realip', time = '".strtotime ("+30 seconds")."'";
$res = mysql_query($sql);

    echo"<b>Invalid Username/Password, Please go back and <a href=index.php>try again!</a></b>";

}else{
die("You did not attempt to login, <a href=index.php>Click</a> here to go to the login page!");
}
?>
```

Comment: `die("-"); exit();` ... now there's a great example of redundancy...

Comment: In case someone needs it: http://codepad.org/MPsalkgX

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /home3/mafiasec/public_html/logincheck.php on line 311

Answer (score 3):

You already have an `else` statement on line 298. You cannot have another `else` following that.

I think this might be because you are missing a matching `}` from your code at line 22 (The `if()` statement does not have closing `}`). I am guessing your `else` statement should match that `if()`, in which case you need to add one `}` before the `else` on line 311.

Also, I agree with the others that you need to clean up your code and use proper spacing. It makes debugging much easier.

Edit: Here's the relevant part for your fixed code:

```
</body>
<?php    } ?>
<?php   
      } else { 

         $sql = "UPDATE users SET nextlogin='".strtotime ("+20 seconds")."' WHERE username='".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."'";
         mysql_query($sql);

         $failtime = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime('+5 hours'));

         mysql_query("INSERT INTO loginfails SET id = '', ip = '$realip', time = '$failtime', username = '$username', password = '$password'");
         $sql = "INSERT INTO loginip SET id = '', ip = '$realip', time = '".strtotime ("+30 seconds")."'";
         $res = mysql_query($sql);

         echo"<b>Invalid Username/Password, Please go back and <a href=index.php>try again!</a></b>";


      }      // Here is the extra } you need to add


   } else {
      die("You did not attempt to login, <a href=index.php>Click</a> here to go to the login page!");
   }
?>
```

Comment: I need some help with where to put what, I am new to PHP.

Comment: Try to put a `}` before line 311 (above where it says `}else{`). Once you have that working, add proper spacings to your code for easier reading and debugging, so you will be able to find your error(s) easier next time.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /home3/mafiasec/public_html/logincheck.php on line 311

Comment: Please see my updated answer. I have added code which shows where you should add the `}`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a "line 311" in the code you gave, but it is ugly as all hell.

I notice that in the final `<?php ... ?>` block, you have a close brace with no corresponding opening brace - this is most likely the cause of the error. You then go on to have an `else` that has no corresponding `if`, followed immediately by another `else`. Two `else`s? What does that even mean?

I strongly recommend re-writing this code from scratch, taking care to organise and format it correctly. That way, you will be able to find and fix errors like this yourself.

Comment: I'm with you, but there is line 311. :) however, such questions should be deleted immediately....

Answer (score 0):

There is no if clause: I think that is the cause of the error.

```
$res = mysql_query($sql);

    echo"<b>Invalid Username/Password, Please go back and <a href=index.php>try again!</a></b>";

}else{
die("You did not attempt to login, <a href=index.php>Click</a> here to go to the login page!");
}
```